# Ends with regular expression - Javascript

Tags: javascript

`"inquisitive".endsWith('ive')` returns `true`.

I want to be able to search for something like `"inquisitive".endsWith(i[a-z]e)`, which is like ends with `'i' and some character after that and then an 'e'`. I don't want to do a substring match, since this method is going to be generic, and for most of the cases will not have regex but simple endsWith logic.

Is there a way, this can be achieved, using vanilla JS?

Comment: `"inquisitive".endsWith(ive)` Er, that sounds like `ive` is a variable?

Comment: I didn't understand the part about regex? This is exactly what regex is for.

Comment: I think regex it the way to go. But has an 'i' some other stuff and ends with 'e' can be tested with `(str.includes('i') && str.endsWith('e'))`. Maybe an example of what you mean by "is going to be generic" will help.

Comment: @CertainPerformance you are correct. Sorry! I meant `"inquisitive".endsWith('ive')`

Comment: @Esko Yes, regex is fine, but endsWith does a string match instead of regex match, I meant.

Comment: Thanks @MarkMeyer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *have* to use only `endsWith` and cannot use a regular expression for whatever odd reason, you can come up with a list of all strings between `'iae'` and `'ize'`:

```js
const allowedStrs = Array.from(
  { length: 26 },
  (_, i) => 'i' + String.fromCharCode(i + 97) + 'e'
);
const test = str => allowedStrs.some(end => str.endsWith(end));
console.log(test('iae'));
console.log(test('ize'));
console.log(test('ife'));
console.log(test('ihe'));
console.log(test('iaf'));
console.log(test('aae'));
```

But that's way more complicated than it should be. If at all possible, change your code to accept the use of a regular expression instead, it's so much simpler, and should be much preferable:

```js
const test = str => /i[a-z]e$/.test(str);
console.log(test('iae'));
console.log(test('ize'));
console.log(test('ife'));
console.log(test('ihe'));
console.log(test('iaf'));
console.log(test('aae'));
```